# Как определить передвижение одного пользователя по нескольким сайтам?

Tags: javascript, php

На сервере есть три сайта: А1, А2, А3. Связанные общей тематикой, но разными направлениями, как понять что пользователь заходил на сайт А1, а так - же на А2/3? Как выдать ему уникальный ID(на эти сайты)?

Answer (score 2):

В первую очередь нужно задать вопрос как вы в принципе идентифицируете пользователя на сайте? Если у вас есть сессии или еще какой-то другой способ, где вы храните ID своих пользователей, то используя эти данные осуществить мониторинг таким способом:

Перед формированием страницы достаем данные пользователя и добавляем пиксель-картинку с необходимыми параметрами данного пользователя, например ID, таким образом:

```html
<body>
  ...

  <img src="https://site.com/pixel.png?params=...">
</body>
```

На своем же сайте, на стороне сервера, делаете перехват данного запроса по адресу `https://site.com/pixel.png`, далее два шага:

- отправляете картинку с одним пикселем
- сканируете параметры запроса `?params=...`, соответственно обрабатываете и находите своего пользователя.

В качестве параметра может быть ID вашего пользователя. Но такие данные в открытом виде передавать нельзя, поэтому можно воспользоваться зашифрованными данными получив токен, который потом можно расшифровать на стороне сервера. Токен можно сформировать один раз, при каждой новой аутентификации пользователя, чтобы токен каждый раз был непредсказуем и выдавал всегда разный резуьтат, добавляем в его содержание дату (в итогде по содержанию будет: ID пользователя и дата аутентификации).

```html
<body>
  ...

  <img src="https://site.com/pixel.png?token=...">
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Для этого вам поможет https://github.com/ramsey/uuid.
Вешаете на одном из сайтов, и регистрируете на 2х других с этим ID-шником